# How to convert ScriptEngine.eval to Java object

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn, scriptengine

I'm using ScriptEngine to run a Javascript. In my case, the Javascript will always return a boolean.  I thought that eval() would return an Object that I can cast, but instead it seems to return a `ScriptObjectMirror`.  toString() returns `[Boolean true]`, so the evaluation is working. How can I convert or cast to a Boolean or boolean?

Here is my code

```
final ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
final ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("javascript");
final Object jsEval = engine.eval(String.format("new Boolean(%s)", jsString));
System.out.printf("*** jsEval: %s %s%n ", jsEval, jsEval.getClass().getName());
```

Output is

```
*** jsEval: [Boolean true] jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the type for sure, you can use the `to` method:

```java
jsEval.to(Boolean.class)
```

Comment: Thank you.  Love when it's such a simple solution.  Obviously, I need to cast to ScriptObjectMirror.  Why does eval() return an Object instead of returning ScriptObjectMirror, or at least some interface

Comment: No idea.  Keep in mind that Nashorn is deprecated since Java-11 and removed since Java15.

Comment: I'm unfortunately still on Java 8 :-(.  I assume that there is a replacement?   Since I'm using `final ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("javascript");`, I assume it will use whatever the current recommended engine is